# Shiny pass input to a reactive function

Tags: shiny

I would like to pass an input to a reactive function in Shiny. Essentially this is to avoid having to define a function twice. I would like to do something of the form:

```
lUpper1 <- fSelectUpperDist(1)
lUpper2 <- fSelectUpperDist(2)
```

where '1' and '2' correspond to the inputs, and there is logic within the reactive function of the form:

```
SelectUpperDist <- reactive({
    aSelection <- ifelse(x==1,input$upperDist1,input$upperDist2)
    'Do something'
    return(aResult)
})
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Best, Ben

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `reactive` to define `lUpper1` and `lUpper2` as reactive expressions:

```
lUpper1 <- reactive({fSelectUpperDist(1)})
lUpper2 <- reactive({fSelectUpperDist(2)})
```

When you need the value, you can call `lUpper1` or `lUpper2`

```
aSelection <- ifelse(x==1,lUpper1(),lUpper2())
```